# ClassCastException when both the variables are floats in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, classcastexception

My code has an `ArrayList` defined as:

`ArrayList<Float> dummyArray = new ArrayList();`

and a `float` variable defined as:

```
float smoothedValue;
```

The code is executed as follows:

```
 if(x==1  && dummyArray.size()>1) //x is an int
{
smoothedValue =  dummyArray.get(dummyArray.size()-1); //Error here
}
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Float
```

The variables are defined inside the same method (a private method in a class) and both are floats (the elements of `ArrayList` are also float). Why am I getting this error? Have I done something wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: This works for me `ArrayList<Float> dummyArray = new ArrayList<Float>();
  dummyArray.add(1.0f);
  float fv = dummyArray.get(0);
  System.out.println(fv);`

Comment: Can you provide a compilabe complete example that shows this error?  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ScaryWombat None of my variable is `Double`, how come I get that error message?

Comment: [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem was that the FLOAT was forcing the getValue cast to use DOUBLE.
After digging more, I got the solution. I used the following approach:

```
Float.valueOf(String.valueOf(double_variable));
```

For example:

```
smoothedValue = Float.valueOf(String.valueOf(dummyArray.get(dummyArray.size()-1)));
```